# Using JQuery to create dataTable. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, datatable

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work.

This is what I import:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

This is my code

```
var myUrl = "test.php";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajax-content').DataTable({
        "ajax": myUrl,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "navn"},
            { "data": "timeStamp"},
            { "data": "logged_in"},
            { "data": "display_status"},
            { "data": "logo"}
        ]
    });
});
```

And this is my JSON

```
{
    "2": {
        "navn": "Henry",
        "timeStamp": "1505222637",
        "logged_in": "not online",
        "display_status": "Doesn't work",
        "logo": "someURL"
    },
    "5": {
        "navn": "Diana",
        "timeStamp": "1505224159",
        "logged_in": "Online",
        "display_status": "Works",
        "logo": "anotherURL"
    }
}
```

Its fine if it can be done without dataTable. I suspect my problem is when I execute the first segment of the code. When I try doing my JQuery.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me come up with a solution :(

**UPDATED:**
Forgot to post a picture of the error it gave me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGBO.png

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: I'm not a dataTable expert, but shouldn't there be an id field too? If you set one in the columns? Is it really expecting an object and not an array?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the picture >_<

Comment: DataTables expect an [array](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), or an [array of objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html). You are providing objects in your JSON. You will have to update your API endpoint to return the correct format.

Comment: take a look to the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: @Terry seems like you were correct. Thank you so much for your help ^_^

Comment: @Terry If you add that comment as the answer. I'll approve it :)

Comment: @Sky Thanks, glad that it helped :) added my comment as answer, with some additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery datatables plugin expects an [array](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), or an [array of objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html), when populating the table with data. You are providing objects in your JSON, which is a format that it does not expect—thereby causing the plugin to break.

There are several options to do fix this:

- Update your API endpoint to return the correct format.
- Manually map your object into an array (Underscore/Lodash have very useful utility functions, if you ever need to parse your object manually)